# Combo Box by default selected the last option

Tags: jquery, html

I want a combobox by default selected the last option (using jquery):

```
<select>
    <option>item1</option>
    <option>item2</option>
    <option>item3</option>
    <option>item4</option>
    <option>item5</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("select option:last").attr("selected", "selected");
});
```

Comment: Use prop instead of attr $("select option:last").prop("selected", true);

Answer (score 14):

A plain JavaScript solution:

```
select.selectedIndex = select.options.length-1;
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/scA9Z/)

Answer (score 2):

```
<select>
    <option>item1</option>
    <option>item2</option>
    <option>item3</option>
    <option>item4</option>
    <option selected="selected">item5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Not enough jQuery! (But seriously, I prefer this to doing it from JS/jQuery.)

Answer (score 2):

Use "prop" instead of "attr", of course depending of what version of jQuery you are using.

$("select option:last").prop("selected", "selected");

jQuery prop:
http://api.jquery.com/prop/

More discussion on the subject of when to use prop or attr:
[.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Answer (score 2):

Just using vanilla Javascript you can combine **.selectedIndex** and **.length** properties of the **< select >** dom object in order to achieve this:

```js
document.querySelector("#mySelect").selectedIndex = document.querySelector("#mySelect").length - 1;
```

```html
<select id="mySelect">
    <option>item1</option>
    <option>item2</option>
    <option>item3</option>
    <option>item4</option>
    <option>item5</option>
</select>
```